# Android Navigation Drawer: How to update the counter value

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in android development and developing a simple notepad application where in I've a Navigation Drawer. Everything is ok, I am able to see navigation drawer and it works fine. now I'm stuck with how to update the counter value in drawer. Nav Drawer displays the categories of the notes and their counts.

How can I update the counter values in the Navigation Drawer when a note is either deleted or added (Notes are saved in db with category value - So I can get the count by doing a simple query ). I've searched thoroughly on internet but couldn't find any example to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Navigation Drawer` is getting items from adapter (since you have custom items, I assume you have your own custom adapter). So once you do any action with the data your adapter serving, you should just push new data to your adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

**EDIT** How this adapter can looks like:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Object> data;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        //do stuff
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        //do stuff
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        //do stuff
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //do stuff
    }

    public void updateData(Cursor cursor){
        data = //fetch data from Cursor
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer nikis, I tried that it seems working by updating the counter value in getView method but I believe this is not a very efficient way as this will lead to access db everytime getView method is called. I want to update the counter only on data is changed in db.

Comment: You shouldn't query your DB in `getView`, I've updated my post with solution: each time you make changes in your db, just fetch new data and push it to something like `updateData` method of your adapter. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, this seems much nicer way to do it. I will try to implement it asap and provide my feedback. Thanks once again for help!

Answer (score 3):

You can add an extra method like `loadData()` in your adapter class and write your codes inside this method. Just get your current data(no. of notes/trash) from database and set it to specific navigation drawer item and finally call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to refresh the dataset.

```
public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return navDrawerItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {      
        return navDrawerItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Write your code

        return convertView;
    }

    public void loadData()
    {
        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(context);

        // Notes and trash counts
        int countNotes = db.getAllActiveNotes().size();
        int countTrash = db.getAllTrashNotes().size();

        String strCountNotes = String.valueOf(countNotes);
        String strCountTrash = String.valueOf(countTrash);

        // Set counter value to Navigation drawer items
        navDrawerItems.get(0).setCount(strCountNotes);
        navDrawerItems.get(1).setCount(strCountTrash);

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Finally, call `loadData()` from method `onDrawerOpened()` where navigation drawer implemented most probably in your main `FragmentActivity` class. As a result, every time when you open the navigation drawer you will see the updated counter value on drawer items.

```
public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

    // Update notes and trash counter
    adapter.loadData();

    getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);

    invalidateOptionsMenu();            
}
```

Hope this will help~